# Symfony 3 - organization a repository class and functions

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 3 project, I have some Entities and Repository. Unfortunately, in a repository file, I can add only get or getAll functions. I want to add for instance function checkBlocked() to check if the user is blocked. Where I should add that function? To Repository file or somewhere else?

Comment: why not just add it as a private method in your service, if checkBlocked() needs DB IO, service i assume will already have your repository injected, so within that method just call the repository do your DB magic and return boolean. And the repo could have the DB related methods only

Comment: What is the checkBlocked() function actually checking? Is it based on a value in the user table, e.g. `user.blocked`? Maybe it is a row in another table, e.g. `blocked_users` or so? Or is it checking something more complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository file should contain anything to do with Database data being returned, whether it be complex queries, or just a query you'll use alot, that is where it should live.

The Entity file is basically an object of the database data also called abstraction. This is done so that no matter what type of database we use we have a way to store it uniformly so that it's database independent, so a perfect example of something I would place in there is the following.

Suppose we have a entity that has both a first name and a last name field:

```
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $firstName
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName): void
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $lasttName
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName): void
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }
```

but lets say we need to get their full name alot, it can be cumbersome to type

`$user->getFirstName() . ' ' . $user->getLastName();`

so why not just add a method to do this for us?

```
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

So in other words it sounds like the checkBlocked method you speak of is a sort of ban system. My guess is you have a database column called blocked which is a tiny int. If this is in fact the case I would say it belongs in the entity.

```
public function getIsUserBlocked()
{
    // return your column here
}
```

Comment: Make sure your Entity which has a repository includes the line `* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Entity\HouseholdRepository")`, replacing `App` with whatever your structure is. Then your repository is the best place for additional functions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, the best place for my checkBlocked()  function will be the Entity class.